# Time Limit Exceeded in Sliding Window Maximum(InterviewBit)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, stack

Given an array of integers A. There is a sliding window of size B which
is moving from the very left of the array to the very right.
You can only see the w numbers in the window. Each time the sliding window moves
rightwards by one position. You have to find the maximum for each window.
The following example will give you more clarity.

The array A is [1 3 -1 -3 5 3 6 7], and B is 3.
Example:

```
Window position         Max
[1 3 -1] -3 5 3 6 7      3
1 [3 -1 -3] 5 3 6 7      3
1 3 [-1 -3 5] 3 6 7      5
1 3 -1 [-3 5 3] 6 7      5  
1 3 -1 -3 [5 3 6] 7      6
1 3 -1 -3 5 [3 6 7]      7
```

```
Input 1:
    A = [1, 3, -1, -3, 5, 3, 6, 7]
    B = 3
Output 1:
    C = [3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7]
```

NOTE: You only need to implement the given function. Do not read input, instead use the arguments to the function. Do not print the output, instead return values as specified.

My Code:

```
class Solution:
    # @param A : tuple of integers
    # @param B : integer
    # @return a list of integers
    def slidingMaximum(self, A, B):
        stack = []
        if B>=len(A):
            return [max(A)]
        else:
            for i in range((len(A))+1-B):
                stack.append(A[i:i+B])
                stack[i]=max(stack[i])
            return stack
```

It's showing me time limit exceeded. Can anyone tell me why?

```
Time Limit Exceeded. Your submission didn't complete in the allocated time limit
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the branch `if B>=len(A):` you are returning single value. There should be `return [max(A)]`